# Converting from VARCHAR to BINARY(16) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have as table with this column and type:

```
sales_channel_id BINARY(16)
```

In the row I have this value: `5DBACA1114B24872ACCFE679037DF670`

I have written this value into another table, but this time the table column has the type `VARCHAR(255)`. In the table I see this value: `5dbaca1114b24872accfe679037df670` (no capitals).

Now I have created another table with a column of type `BINARY(16)`. When I make something like this to transform the data from the varchar column to the new column like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
setting_sales_channel (sales_channel_id)
SELECT sales_channel_id from mcn_setting
```

I get the error: `Query 1 ERROR: Data too long for column 'sales_channel_id' at row 1`

Why does this happen and how can I transfer the data from the VARCHAR column into the new column which is of type BINARY(16)?

Comment: Can you replicate a sample of your environment (and your output error) in a fiddle site like https://www.db-fiddle.com/?

Comment: You can see it here with a simple insert: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXbFdM9P4TNuC1mibaXagR/0

Comment: @Torben Do you want to use `UNHEX()`? What you have is a 32 character long string, which will not fit into a 16 bytes long column.

Comment: I don't know how many things like this you have to do, or how often, but if you want to do it with the difficulty curve of an Excel file, download and install Microsoft Workbench, and you can do ALTER commands with right clicks ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**change your query to:**

```
INSERT INTO 
setting_sales_channel (sales_channel_id)
SELECT CONVERT(sales_channel_id,BINARY(16)) from mcn_setting;
```

**sample (MariaDB)**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> show create table b;
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| b     | CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bbinary` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> show create table bs;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| bs    | CREATE TABLE `bs` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bvarchar` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from b;
Empty set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from bs;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | bvarchar                         |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | 5dbaca1114b24872accfe679037df670 |
+----+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> 
MariaDB [bernd]> INSERT INTO b (bbinary) 
    -> SELECT CONVERT(bvarchar,BINARY(16))  FROM bs;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.003 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from bs;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | bvarchar                         |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | 5dbaca1114b24872accfe679037df670 |
+----+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: Then I get this error: `Query 1 ERROR: Truncated incorrect BINARY(16) value: '5dbaca1114b24872accfe679037df670'`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked when using `UNHEX` now. The result looked like this:

```
INSERT INTO setting_sales_channel (sales_channel_id)
SELECT UNHEX(sales_channel_id) from setting;
```